Adding bumpers to a custom robot
I have build a custom robot were I want to add bumpers to, the robot is square and has 2 bumpers on each side. At the moment I read each bumper state and each bumper publish this onto it's own topic.
From here it's a bit unclear to me what the correct way is to further incorporate the bumpers into the whole ros2 environment so that nav2 can use it.
I read some other topics about this matter and see that bumper to pointcloud seems to be a solution that is used for this. I did add the bumpers into the robots urdf, is there a way to use this in combination with the published state to detect a bumper pressed on the bumper location? If bumper to pointcloud is the only solution for this, how can I create a pointcloud for my custom 8 bumpers?
Edit:
I used the bumper2pc method to create pointcloud2 hits on the bumper locations, 1 point in the middle of a bumper location. I added the pointcloud2 to the local_costmap as follow:
observation_sources: scan pointcloud
scan:
  topic: /scan
  max_obstacle_height: 2.0
  clearing: True
  marking: True
  data_type: "LaserScan"
  raytrace_max_range: 3.0
  raytrace_min_range: 0.0
  obstacle_max_range: 2.5
  obstacle_min_range: 0.0
pointcloud:
  topic: /bumper_point_cloud
  max_obstacle_height: 2.0
  clearing: False
  marking: True
  data_type: "PointCloud2"
  raytrace_max_range: 3.0
  raytrace_min_range: 0.0
  obstacle_max_range: 2.5
  obstacle_min_range: 0.0  

Although I can see the bumpers pointcloud hits in Rviz, the local costmap doesn't do anything with it.
Is my local_costmap setup wrong for the pointcloud or did I miss something else?
Thanks in advance. If you need any more information just let me know and I will update the question.
